# How do I produce a sawtooth waveform using c language?

Tags: c, microcontroller, dac

This is my program with regards to DAC using PIC18F97J60. I am new to this and already struggling alot so please do not judge me.

```
#include <P18F97J60.h>
//#include <delays.h>
//#include "delays.c"

void SPI1init(void);
void SPI1out(char Code);

void SPI1init(void)
{
    SSP1CON1 = 0b00100010;  // Enable SPI, CKP=0, Master, Fosc/64
    SSP1STATbits.CKE = 1;   // CKE=1, (rising edge for shift register)
    TRISCbits.TRISC3 = 0;   // RC3 is SCk
    TRISCbits.TRISC5 = 0;   // RC5 is SDO
    SPI1out(0x00);
}

void SPI1out(char Code)
{
    SSP1BUF = Code;         // Transmit
    while(SSP1STATbits.BF==0);  // Wait for END (Receipt Buffer Full)
    Code = SSP1BUF;         // Just read to clear BF
}
```

Diagram for the circuit: https://ibb.co/M1cChNB

Question of the assignment: https://ibb.co/rwz3kwP

Comment: what does it look like on the scope?

Comment: did you try bit banging it?

Comment: It's  in the image links

Comment: @<old_timer> due to COVID-19 we cannot visit the lab to do experimenting on sawtooth waveform unfortunately and this is an assessment for me to test out how can I generate the waveform

Comment: Following your second comment @old_timer, I don't know how to do bit-banging as I've never heard about it. Please write the code Below in the comment section for easier understanding.

Comment: you look at the documentation for the part in question (your dac) and notice the timing diagram for chip select, clock and data.  Using gpio pins as gpio pins (not spi controller going through gpio pins) make the pins go high and low at the right time with some delays in between.  that is bit banging.  getting a spi controller to work without a scope can be tricky.  you need to do more to debug this

Comment: is the problem that you cant change/set the dac output to a level or that you cant wrap that in a loop that creates the sawtooth pattern?

Comment: Well tbh with you @old_timer we aren't taught how to produce a sawtooth waveform as this is something we should research online regardless of code or documentation

Comment: Now come on.  DAC means digital to analog converter.  You put in a digital number you get out an analog voltage that represents that number the bigger the number the bigger the voltage.  Look at the picture.  Think about gradeschool algebra.  its a straight line.  set a one set a two set a three set a four....if the time between setting the values is the same you will get a straight line, when you get to the max voltage you want start back at the bottom. y = mx+b x is evenly spaced in time.

Comment: read the dac specs for how fast it can react, the update rate, update slower than that either using a delay or you might be able to adjust the spi clock rate so that one spi transaction takes at least that long.  spi is not a fixed rate thing, no reason to go as fast as the part can handle, sometimes good to go slower, you can often go really really slow (read the specs for the part).   you might need to use a timer to insure that the times that you start sending values to the dac is evenly spaced.

Comment: @old_timer I suck as a programmer and I don't even understand the dac specs

Comment: @old_timer This is the link for data specs: file:///C:/Users/muhdi/Downloads/1661fb.html